# What is the connection between "interval of definition" and "solution curve" for an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading in Zill's Book on advanced engineering mathematics and I am reading in the part related to Ordinary differential equations , I am confused regarding the connection between **Interval of definition** and **Domain** of a
function and **solution curve** , I have mainly two questions :

1. Is the **Interval of definition** is that portion of the domain where the function is both

   - **Continuous**
   - **Differentiable**

   While the in case of the function's domain it needs only to be **Continuous** and not necessarily  **Differentiable** ?
2. For the following Example in the screenshot , Why do we say that interval of definition is
   either (-inf,0) **OR** (0,+inf) and not saying its **(-inf,0) U (0,+inf)** *since zero is
   already excluded* and the function is not differentiable at 0 which is already excluded in the
   later interval that have a gap at 0 why do we have to take either segments (intervals)
   individually ?

[image: Screenshot of the example]

For reference also here is how it defined the **Interval of definition** and **Solution curve** :
[image: Definitions]

Thanks

Comment: Since $\-infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ is not an interval

Comment: Do you mean by definition of interval , it should not contain gaps ?

Comment: Yes an interval never has gaps.

Comment: thanks too much